# Trouble detecting item used

Tags: if-statement, minecraft, bukkit

I am trying to check if the item the player used is the custom item I added but for some reason it is not detecting the item. Here is the code.

```
@EventHandler
public void damage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event){
    if(event.getEntity() instanceof Player && event.getDamager() instanceof Player){
        if(((Player) event.getDamager()).getInventory().getItemInMainHand() == CustomItems.potator()){
            System.out.println("potato");
        }
        else{
            //When i looked @ console this logged the same exact thing
            System.out.println("Damager Main Item = " + ((Player) event.getDamager()).getInventory().getItemInMainHand());
            System.out.println("Potator Item = " + CustomItems.potator());
        }
    }
}
```

Custom Item Class:

```
public static ItemStack potator(){

    ArrayList<String> lore = new ArrayList<String>();
    lore.add(ChatColor.GOLD + "Turns a random slot in the hotbar to a potato.");
    lore.add(ChatColor.GRAY + "1/100% chance from dropping from a potato.");

    ItemStack item = new ItemStack(Material.STONE_HOE);
    ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();
    meta.setDisplayName(ChatColor.GOLD + "The Potator");
    meta.setLore(lore);
    item.setItemMeta(meta);
    return item;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
if(((Player) event.getDamager()).getInventory().getItemInMainHand() == CustomItems.potator())
```

In this line, by using `==`, you're checking if the left and right-hand references are the same. You want to do content comparison, e.g. using `.equals()`. There's a good explanation of the differences on [GeeksForGeeks](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-equals-method-java/).

Spigot provides a stack size independent method [`isSimilar()`](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/inventory/ItemStack.html#isSimilar-org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack-) which would be better than `.equals()`.

However, this would likely make your code execute for any stone hoe so you'll need to do your own checks. I would do something like this:

```java
public boolean isPotator(ItemStack i){
    if(i == null || !i.hasItemMeta())
        return false;
    ItemMeta meta = i.getItemMeta();
    if(!meta.hasDisplayName() || !meta.hasLore())
        return false;
    return meta.getDisplayName().equals(ChatColor.GOLD + "The Potator");
}
```

And then perform your check like so:

```java
@EventHandler
public void damage(EntityDamageByEntityEvent event)
{
    if(!(event.getEntity() instanceof Player && event.getDamager() instanceof Player))
        return;
    Player damager = (Player) event.getDamager();
    if(!isPotator(damager.getInventory().getItemInMainHand()))
        return;
    System.out.println("potato");
}
```

Since you have a `CustomItem` class, you can better this code by making a final string for the item name, which you can then use in both the ItemStack creation and the `isPotator` check.